# Easy way to update 200 reports to add a new filter?

Tags: apex, reporting

My client is expanding their business into U.K. and wants me to work on the below requirements.

1. Update all the existing 200 reports to exclude the newly added
   custom country field value U.K.
2. Clone existing 200 reports and add a new filter for newly added custom country field value U.K.

Now the task is on me, I am just exploring options to see if there is a easy way to do this instead of clicking through each of these??

Anybody worked on this kind of requirement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can follow below steps.

1. You can use ant migration tool or eclipse to retrieve all reports from your current org in eclipse.
2. Open all 200 .report file in notepad++ or any other text editor. replace exiting filter with your new filter
3. deploy again your updated reports using any migration tool or eclipse.

You can follow same process for cloning purpose.

Comment: This was my first thought but there is no country filter for existing reports, I need to add new filter condition.

Comment: are you not able to add new filter ? <filter>
        <criteriaItems>
            <column>Account.Country__c</column>
            <operator>equals</operator>
            <value>U.K.</value>
        </criteriaItems>
    </filter>

Answer (score 1):

the easiest way is to work on 1 or 2 manually, using whatever software you need to. then once you have the format of the output, and where it belongs in the file, you can then use notepad as himanshu explained.

taking it one step further, you can write a simple script that will open the file, insert your changes, and save the file. this will save time and you'll be done long before expected!